# Genes are linearly arranged on the chromosome

Tags: genetics

Could someone please explain the meaning of the statement given by TH Morgan:

"genes are linearly arranged on chromosomes"

Since according to my knowledge there are noncoding parts in between.

Comment: Can you give more information about why the existence of noncoding segments precludes a linear arrangement? A linear arrangement of genes could imply the linear arrangement of all the stuff in between, no?

Comment: *Too long for a comment* (But I don't have enough reputation so...) Check the following: 1. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1091521/
2. https://s4.lite.msu.edu/res/msu/botonl/b_online/e11/11b.htm#:~:text=Genes%20Are%20Arranged%20on%20Chromosomes,sometimes%20separated%20from%20each%20other.
3. https://www.britannica.com/science/theory-of-linear-arrangement-of-genes 4. https://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/thomas-hunt-morgan-genetic-recombination-and-gene-496/ Informative and a good read :)

Comment: And have you any idea of when TH Morgan said that? And what the state of knowledge about the chemical structure of the chromosome was at the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This combines two important findings to which Morgan's lab contributed.

- Genes on the chromosome: They could show that mutated phenotypes were linked to the physical entity of chromosomes.
- Arranged linearly: They could show that there are distances between different phenotypes correlated to a specific linear arrangement. These distances correspond to the physical distance on these chromosomes (and thus how frequently they are co-inherited). More specifically they showed that distances suggest that the space is linear,  e.g.: in ---A--B-------C-D-   , A would be commonly inherited with B, but less so with C, and even less with D ... ; Theoretically one could have also thought that the chromosomes are circular (as they indeed are in some bacteria) or adopt an even more complex shape, e.g.: some net-like meshwork on which mutated phenotypes / genes sit. In these other cases one would anticipate more complex patterns of co-inheritance among all pairs of genes relative to a linear arrangement.

Comment: This is a very good answer and I'd like to upvote it, but it doesn't have references. Please help by adding them. :)

Comment: @David I wasn't the one who posted this question!

Comment: @Adhish Whoops. Sorry.